# Python input pipe buffering

Tags: python, pipe, stdin

I'm having trouble understanding why `input` is not printing to stdout immediately from the child forked process. Instead, it waits for the parent to write to its pipe (which should map to sys.stdin). Is it something to do with buffering?

```
import os
import select
import sys

r, w = os.pipe()
pid = os.fork()

if pid:
    try:
        os.close(r)

        b = b''
        while True:
            ins, _, _ = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 1)
            if ins:
                d = os.read(0, 1)
                print('parent read', d)
                if d == b'\n':
                    break
                b += d
        print('parent writing', b)
        os.write(w, b)
    finally:
        os.close(w)
else:
    os.close(w)
    sys.stdin.close()
    sys.stdin = os.fdopen(r)
    print('asking for input')
    d = raw_input('Enter your input: ')
    print(d)
    sys.exit(0)
```

And the output:

```
python2 p2.py
asking for input
a
('parent read', 'a')
('parent read', '\n')
('parent writing', 'a')
Enter your input: a
```

Whereas under python3 (changing raw_input to input) it works as expected:

```
python3 test.py
asking for input
Enter your input: a
parent read b'a'
parent read b'\n'
parent writing b'a'
a
```

Comment: Can be fixed by doing `os.fdopen(r, 'r', 1)` or running with `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 python2 p2.py` or `python2 -u p2.py`. I think the first approach is the best since it doesn't affect stdout and other processes

Comment: Curiously, python 2's fdopen is a cpython posix implementation, whereas in python 3, fdopen is a wrapper around io.open. Using io.open in python 2, I encounter the same issue, regardless of the buffer size I set (the other two methods mentioned above still work though).